# Github - can't connect via ssh from time to time

Tags: git, github, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

### Situation

I'm using linux (*mint mate 17.2*), when push to github via ssh, from time to time connection fails, usually it resume after reboot computer & network. After several days, it might become bad again, quite confusing.

Push via http never has such issue, but it requires password which is not convenient.

### Debug info

When push via ssh:

> debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.

It stuck at the above line.

Then after a long wait, get timeout tip:

> debug1: connect to address 192.30.252.129 port 22: Connection timed out
>
> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

### Questions:

What could be the reason, how to fix that?

---

### More debug info:

**ping is good:**

```
eric@eric-pc:~$ ping 192.30.252.129
PING 192.30.252.129 (192.30.252.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=345 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=452 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=373 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=349 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=346 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=6 ttl=50 time=442 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=7 ttl=50 time=344 ms
```

**telnet is bad:**

```
eric@eric-pc:~$ telnet 192.30.252.129 22
Trying 192.30.252.129...
```

---

### @Update:

I setup another computer in the same network, with the same ssh key, it succeed to push to github via ssh, while the original computer still get timeout.

**Actions:**

- **Restart the network**, it still can't connect.
- **Restart the ssh-agent**, it still can't connect, the old process become a defunct ssh-agent process, while there is a new ssh-agent:

```
    eric      2552  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Jan08   0:00 [ssh-agent] 
    eric     27080  0.0  0.0  10628   316 ?        Ss   15:26   0:00 ssh-agent
    eric     27168  0.0  0.0  17028  2548 pts/7    S+   15:27   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent
```

- **Reboot linux**, then ssh works,

**Guess:**

- ssh-agent has issue,
- github blocked my client due to some reason,

Actually, before ask, from google, I saw similar question, but none solved the issue, and none explained the reason.

And this issue is really annoying, because I don't want to input password every time push, and also don't want to reboot my pc from time to time, any help?

Comment: Is there any more output at higher debug level? Can you connect using different application? (for example `telnet 192.30.252.129 22` should return a banner) If you have a different machine on the same network - can you connect from it when the first one is stuck? Are you using control sockets? (ControlMaster / ControlPath variables in your ssh config)

Comment: @viraptor debug3 is used, which is the highest, ping & telnet result is added in the question, I setup another computer in the network with the same ssh key, it succeed to push via ssh, while the original computer still can't. I am not using control sockets.

Comment: This problem may be caused by a firewall on the failing machine

Comment: @Ferrybig I am using mint mate, the only firewall is ufw, and it allows port 22, but it's the remote port that matters, not the local port, right? And, the firewall is always there, ssh just suddenly unavailable while machine is running, so I think it's not the local firewall issue.

Comment: @EricWang Did not know from the context that you were using linux, Seriously, I have seen some buggy windows firewall products that gave the weird symptoms that you had.

Comment: @Ferrybig Yeah, that's one of the reason that I haven't use windows for many years.

Comment: Is there another machine in the network with the same IP address? These symptons remind me of that problem.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós The network is using DHCP to allocate ip to clients, so there shouldn't have duplicated ip address, and I just checked the router's admin page, there is no duplicated ip ... , when ssh not available, other websites are still available, so the network is fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your git default ssh port using the command 
`$ git remote add origin ssh://user@host:1234/srv/git/example` and your ssh port to 1234. you can use anyother port you like rather than 1234 (larger than 1000 are recommended).see if it can solve your problem. :)

.try changing your ~/.ssh/config file if doesn't exit create one.

`Host github.com
Port 22
Host *
Port 1234`

Comment: The repo in on github, I have no right to change github's ssh port.

Comment: As it is a connection time out this means you are reachable to git network but port you are connecting is not responding so it is a port problem for sure.see my edited answer.

Comment: Why do you think that running ssh on a port > 1024 is a good idea??

Comment: I don't think add `Port 1234` will solve the issue, because you are trying to change port of github, that's impossible, anyhow I tried your config it didn't solve it.