# bash - Switch git protocol for multiple git repository via bash

Tags: git, bash, shell, sed

On linux, there are some git repo, whose `.git/config` contain following 3 lines:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-eo:eric/workspace.git
    # url = https://eric@github.com/eric/workspace.git
```

(*Tip: the last 2 line begin with a tab.*)

**The question is:**

- I want to move the `#` from 3rd line to 2nd line by bash, via sed maybe, and also be able to move it back. I mean trigger the 2 lines, how to call the sed in bash?

---

### @Update:

**Choose protocol via argument to script:**

Actually, I will provide an argument to the script, it should be either `ssh` or `https`, the argument will decide which line to uncomment, and which to comment, if a line for one of the 2 protocol don't exists, then ignore it.

By the way, I just need the sed part to modify the 2 lines, I can write other parts of the bash, to save your time.

**Reason I want to do this:**

I want to do this, because sometime `ssh` won't work due to network or github bug, I don't know, at that time I need to switch all git repo from `ssh` to `https`, but when `ssh` works well, I will use it because I don't need to input password each time.

I have also asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736817/github-cant-connect-via-ssh-from-time-to-time) about why ssh not working from time to time, but not solved, so I have to write a script to help trigger it with one command.

---

### Summary:

Thanks for answers & comments, I would summary the solutions as following.

**Solutions:**

- Use `bash` & `sed`, see the answer by `Eric Wang` (*me*). It works for linux I guess, mac might need some modification for the `tab` match, windows might can't use it.
- Use `bash` & `awk`, see answer by `anubhava`.
- Define multiple remote, 1 for ssh, 1 for https, then choosing protocol by select the remote, see comments under question by `William Pursell`. This would work for all system I guess.
- Use `[include]` to another file that specify the protocol lines, and change the soft link when need, could write a shell script to help switch the soft link instead of change file content, see comments under question by `gniourf_gniourf`. This works at least for unix-like system I guess.

Comment: What is input file has only one line i.e. `\turl = git@github-eo:ericoudesu/linux_workspace.git` ? Should it still be commented?

Comment: @anubhava I updated the question, please see that.

Comment: maybe, you just want to introduce another remote? I mean one remote being dedicated for read-only `https://` and another - for r/w `ssh://`?

Comment: @user3159253 I updated the question to explained why I need the script, please refer to that.

Comment: Have you tried writing the `sed` commands to do what you want here?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, the `tab` part is confusing to me, I didn't succeed yet.

Comment: @EricWang you have explained why you want to switch between ssh and https, but you have not explained why using different remotes doesn't solve the problem for you.

Comment: Using two remotes would add some complexity to day-to-day operation as it would break some handy git automagic as well as increase the chances of a branch starting from an incorrect location (because one of the remotes was incorrectly behind). That said it would work with some extra care.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't understand why another remote would solve the issue. As I said, I want to switch to https protocol only when ssh can't connect due to some unknow reason.

Comment: The other remote can't be incorrectly behing, because "originhttps" and "origin" are just the different local names for the same remote.  I strongly suspect you would be happier using different names for the remote than trying to tweak the config file with a script like this.

Comment: In this very case, you could proceed differently: have two (or more) extra files that contain the protocol, use a soft link and an `[include]` statement; it's then nearly trivial to change the file the link points to, instead of editing the file.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, that's the first version I wrote, I create `config.ssh` and `config.https` for each repo, then just copy one of them and replace the `config`, but in that case I have to maintain the 2 additional file for each repo everytime I change some configuration, which is trivial and easy to introduce mistake.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant… I didn't mean 2 different config files; I meant a single config file, but with an `[include]` directive, that will include the protocol file (this file being a link pointing to one of the 2 protocol files).

Comment: @WilliamPursell Now I understand that better, yes, that would be a simpler solution. But in my case, I defined a lot shortcut comment for git, e.g `gauto` means add + commit + push. In that case, I need to add a duplication shortcut for each remote, that would be hard to remember. But, that's a great solution for sure. Anyhow, since I already finished the script, I would stick with it first until it won't work.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ok, I see, that's another solution, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` might be better option here:

```
awk -v kw='(https|ssh):' 'p ~ /^\turl/ && $0 ~ kw && $0 ~ /^\t#[[:blank:]]*url/ {
   sub(/^\t/, "\t# ", p)
   sub(/^\t*#[[:blank:]]*/, "\t")
}
p!="" {
   print p
}
{
   p=$0
}
END {
   print p
}' file

[remote "origin"]
    # url = git@github-eo:eric/workspace.git
    url = https://eric@github.com/eric/workspace.git
```

Comment: I tested it, it seems the uncommented line has a space after tab, can u help remove that?

Comment: Thank u very much, I think that's a solution. But I have just figured out how to do that in sed, see my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to do that via `sed`, following is the script:

---

### Code

**git_protocol_switch.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# repo array,
repo_arr=(
    "/mnt/star/git_repository/workspace" 
    "/media/ERIC/node"
    "/mnt/star/workplace/eclipse_j2ee_workplace/eric"
)

protocol="null"

url_prefix_comment=""
url_prefix_uncomment=""

repo_count=0

# read protocol,
if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
    protocol=$1
fi

# check protocol,
if [ $protocol == "ssh" ]; then
    url_prefix_comment="https"
    url_prefix_uncomment="git"
elif [ $protocol == "https" ]; then
    url_prefix_comment="git"
    url_prefix_uncomment="https"
else
    echo "invalid protocol: $protocol"
    exit 1;
fi


# switch protocol for repo in array,
for i in "${!repo_arr[@]}"; do 
    if [ -d "${repo_arr[$i]}" ]; then
        sed -i "s/^\turl = $url_prefix_comment/\t# url = $url_prefix_comment/g" "${repo_arr[$i]}/.git/config"
        sed -i "s/^\t# url = $url_prefix_uncomment/\turl = $url_prefix_uncomment/g" "${repo_arr[$i]}/.git/config"

        repo_count=$(expr $repo_count + 1)
    else
        echo "non exists repo: ${repo_arr[$i]}"
    fi
done

echo "Done, switch to protocol [$protocol], repo count: {$repo_count}."

exit 0
```

---

### Call it

```
# switch to ssh
./git_protocol_switch.sh ssh


# switch to https
./git_protocol_switch.sh https
```

---

### What it do

It will help to switch protocol for all repo listed in the bash array.
Ofcause, need to add the 2 line for 2 protocol for each repo first by hand.

Cheers :}